# Libinput 3 finger gestures

Tags: xorg, gnome3, libinput, multi-touch

As I want to get 3-finger (or even 4-finger) gestures running under Gnome (Fedora 25, Xorg), I've installed the libinput drivers and libinput-gestures (https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures).

When trying to debug why 3-finger swipes aren't working, I noticed that `libinput-gestures -r` does not show anything done with more than two fingers.

Does anybody have an idea how to get this working?

The touchpad does support multitouch with at least 3 fingers (I've used it regularly under Windows).
System I use: Dell XPS 15 L501x

xinput-output:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Properties:

```
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (152):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (290): 0
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (291): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (292):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (293):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (294):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (295):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (296):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (297):  1, 0
libinput Accel Speed (298): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (299): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (300):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (301):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (275): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (276):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (277):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (302): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (303): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (304):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (305):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (306):   1, 0, 0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (307):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (308):    1
Device Node (278):  "/dev/input/event5"
Device Product ID (279):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (309):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (310):   1
```